# Print data even if it is null/empty/none existed. Note: some cells doesn't exist

Tags: php, sql, printing

I have a problem where I have searched for hours for a solution. But until now, I haven't found any. The problem is that I have the following query:

```
$sql    = "SELECT
           MONTH( i.invoicedate ) AS month,
           ROUND(SUM(t.transactions * ( t.selling_price - t.buyin ) ),0) AS margin
           FROM invoice i, project p, transactions t, users u
           WHERE 
               t.project = p.proj_id AND 
               t.invoice = f.inv_id AND 
               p.proj_owner = u.usr_id AND 
               YEAR( i.invoice_date ) = '2012' AND
                   u.usr_login = '" . $current_user->first_name . "'
           GROUP BY MONTH( i.invoice_date )
           UNION
           SELECT DISTINCT
               MONTH(p.invoicedate) AS month,
               SUM( ROUND( p.quantity * p.listprice - IF( p.discount_percent > 0,
               p.quantity * p.listprice * p.discount_percent / 100, 0 ) - IF( i.discount_amount > 0, p.discount_amount, 0 ), 0 ) ) - SUM( ROUND( p.quantity * purchaseprice, 0 ) ) AS margin
           FROM productrel p
           LEFT JOIN invoice f ON i.id=f.invoiceid 
           LEFT JOIN entity e ON e.id=f.invoiceid
           LEFT JOIN salesorder s ON f.salesorderid = s.salesorderid
           LEFT JOIN entity t ON t.id=s.salesorderid
           LEFT JOIN users d ON t.ownerid=d.id
           WHERE 
               e.deleted=0 AND
               t.ownerid <> 15 AND
               d.id = " . $current_user->id . " AND
               YEAR(f.invoicedate)='2012'
               GROUP BY MONTH(f.invoicedate)";

$result = $adb->pquery($sql, array());
while ($row = $adb->fetch_array($result)) {
  $margin .= $row['margin'].', ';                                                                       
}
```

With this query, the output looks like this:

```
-------------------------------
|   Month    |    Margin      |
|-----------------------------
|     5      |     3824       |
|    11      |    24344       |
|    12      |    45664       |
|            |                |
```

The main problem is that I want to display the data from this user from all months. Even it is null. To make it a little bit worse is that a lot of the cells doesn't show up, as you can see in the example. So what I want is this:

```
-------------------------------
|   Month    |    Margin      |
|-----------------------------
|     1      |      0         |
|     2      |      0         |
|     3      |      0         |
|     4      |      0         |
|     5      |     3824       |
|     6      |      0         |
|     7      |      0         |
|     8      |      0         |
|     9      |      0         |
|    10      |      0         |
|    11      |    24344       |
|    12      |    45664       |
|            |                |
```

Formatted like this, if I print it with PHP:

0, 0, 0, 0, 3824, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24344, 45664

One last note: It isn't possible to make an additional table with this data, because I do not have the rights to do it.

Comment: Change implicit joins with explicit `left outer join`.

Comment: In MySQL LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are identical. The OUTER keyword is optional. 

You seem in fact to be comparing LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and FULL OUTER JOIN. 

FULL [OUTER] JOIN is not a recognised construct in MySQL. You have to use a workaround with UNION instead.

Comment: I don't see how using `left outer join` will solve this issue anyway, there's nothing here that indicates the existence of a table which is guaranteed to contain all months from `1-13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping for every month, and outputting the value if there is one from the database, or `0` if not. For example;

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $adb->fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $rows[$row['month']] = $row['margin'];
}
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $margin .= (isset($rows[$i]) ? $rows[$i] : 0) . ', ';
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is the solution. I want to thank you for your help!